# Is it ok to "advertise" for Area 51 sites in comments on SO questions?

Tags: discussion, comments, area-51

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824988/logistic-regression-for-advertising-analysis-in-r#comment29477985_19824988) comment seems like it is at best a non-sequitur, asking the OP to support an Area 51 site:

[image]

It feels kind of like a "cold call" pitch. Maybe if there had been a discussion that led up to it, it wouldn't seem so out of place.

Should comments like these be flagged?

Comment: No. I have flagged it.

Comment: If it's just there for the sake of it, absolutely flag it - it's dependent on context.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anwy2MPT5RE

Comment: Advertising has no place in the Noble Confines of Stackhood.

Comment: Am I the only one (along with the user that posted the comment, obviously) that thinks we should be pointing questions that would be perfect for a new site / proposal for a site to that site? But I agree that that comment could use a bit of work.

Comment: @Dukeling If the comment had said simply "This question might be a better fit for AI Stackexchange", I probably would have disagreed (in this particular case), but I wouldn't have thought to flag it. There's a difference between advocating moving a question to a more appropriate site, and trying to get a person to join an Area 51 proposal. One's focused on the question, the other is focused on the person.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although A51 is in-network, no, people shouldn't just plug a proposal on any related question (and especially not unrelated ones!). Flag such usage as "not constructive" and perhaps post a comment explaining that they shouldn't post such comments and/or pointing them at this or another meta post on the subject.